# How do I specify columns when loading new rows into PostgreSQL using pg_bulkload

Tags: postgresql

I'm experimenting with using the pg_bulkload project to import millions of rows of data into a database.  However, none of the new rows have a primary key and only two of several columns are avalable in my input file.  How do I tell pg_bulkload which columns I'm importing and how do I generate the primary key field?  Do I need to edit my import file to match exactly what the output of a COPY command would be and generate the `id` field myself?

For example, lets say my database columns might be:

```
id         title        body        published
```

The data that I have is limited to `title` and `published` and are listed in a tab delimited file.  My `.ctl` file looks like this:

```
TABLE = posts
INFILE = stdin
TYPE = CSV
DELIMITER = "   "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FILTER` functionality of pg_loader. Something like:

In database

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_bulkload_filter(text, text) RETURNS record
AS $$
  SELECT nextval('tablename_id_seq'), NULL, NULL, $1, $2, NULL
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And in pg_bulkload control file:

FILTER = pg_bulkload_filter

Comment: This does the trick.  Looking back, it is in the documentation but it isn't too clear.  Also, I had to cast everything, even the NULL values, to the appropriate types.  Thanks for your help.